# How do I workaround this new warning in Xcode 4.3.1: "Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points..."?

Tags: xcode, ios5, warnings, uistoryboard

I have an iOS project with a storyboard.  I recently upgraded to Xcode 4.3.1, and now this new warning appears:

"Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:."

The problem is that I have some Navigation Controllers in the storyboard with no entry points to them.  The reason I have them is so that I can embed other views in them to see the nav bar at design time in Xcode.  The actual navigation controller these views are pushed onto at runtime are not  in the storyboard (old code that hasn't been ported to the storyboard yet).

Has anyone found a nice workaround for this?  I would like to keep my code clean without warnings.

Comment: If you want it simply to see what a navigation bar looks like with your UI, you can set the Simulated Top Bar to "Navigation Bar" on your scene. It will cause a navigation bar to be displayed with in the scene (and will even automatically propagate down any push segues).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can just set an identifier.  In Xcode >5 on the identity inspector on the right pane, you'll find a field called "Storyboard ID".  Put any string in there, and Xcode will be happy again.

It just wants to know you could reach it (via that identifier) if you wanted to.

Comment: where is the "Identifier" section? i can't seem to find it

Comment: Select the view controller, then the "Utilities" pane which is on the far left.  It has several tabs, the 4th from the left is "Attributes".  That tab has "Simulated Metrics" and "View Controller" sections.  The "Identifier" is in the View Controller section.

Comment: @danh I can't find any "Identifier" in View Controller section. ( My Xcode version is 4.6)

Comment: Its "Storyboard ID" in 4.6.

Comment: In Xcode 5.1 it is under 'Identity Inspector' tab instead of 'Attributes' and its name is "Storyboard ID'.

Comment: Damn so simple yet so effective, who can't help but love this answer me wonders

Comment: I would have expected this to work, but in my case the warning has not gone away. I have some nav controllers that are not the initial view controller but I added them so the subsequent vc's infer the nav bar without me having to add it in manually. EDIT: clearing derived data and restarting Xcode may have helped.

Answer (score 16):

In newer versions of Xcode: Just set a title in `Title` in the Attributes Inspector and then set an identifier in the `Storyboard ID` in the Identity Inspector of your controller.

Answer (score 10):

You may have accidentally copied and pasted a view controller on top of the real one.

Try dragging the offending view to see if there's anything underneath.

Comment: I have no idea why this is at 0 points, this exactly was my problem! I was trying to copy/paste a view controller and i thought it wasn't doing it , but it was just placing it exactly over the old one. Thanks!

Comment: Oh god, why?..) I've cloned it twice! Thanks for clue

Comment: Made this mistake too. I'll remember this one!

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the navigation controller and under the attributes inspector click the button "is initial view controller", this should work too

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 6 - you might be getting this error if you have a new view controller that is standing by itself. You might have created it and did not use a segue to connect the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an identifier for each ViewController (including navigation controller) in "Storyboard ID" field of "Identity Inspector" pane.

In the "Attribute Inspector" pane scroll down to the "View Controller" section and if the "is Initial View Controller" is not checked, check this.

Now run the app.

Answer (score 0):

**Title:**  Setting "is Initial View Controller" (Using Xcode 6.1)

**Background:** Build Failed with "Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:."

Just installed Xcode and first time user, so apologize in advance if explanations are lacking appropriate terminology.

**Resolution:** In my case, the "is Initial View Controller" check box was not checked

"is Initial View Controller" property can be found on the far right pane of the default Xcode window or is under --> View --> Utilities --> Show Attribute Inspector

If you don't see any properties set in the "Attribute Inspector", select the "View Controller" in the story board area. The little round button with a square in the middle (or the first button on the left)

When you select the "View Controller" you should see that the "Attribute Inspector" box is now populated with various property settings.

In the "Attribute Inspector" pane scroll down to the "View Controller" section and if the "is Initial View Controller" is not checked, check this.

Now Run the project. Hope this helps and works.